# Gradle with Apache Jena 3.11.0

Tags: gradle, jena, shadowjar

I am trying to create a shadowjar including the latest Apache Jena 3.11 using the gradle build system and additional java code to create an "uber" package. To do so I found information here: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/notes/jena-repack.html however I am having difficulty to translate this to a gradle setup.

Does anyone knows how to achieve this?

```
5 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 4 up-to-date
Creating memory store
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at nl.wur.ssb.RDFSimpleCon.RDFSimpleCon.createEmptyStore(RDFSimpleCon.java:150)
    at nl.wur.ssb.RDFSimpleCon.RDFSimpleCon.<init>(RDFSimpleCon.java:62)
    at nl.wur.ssb.RDFSimpleCon.RDFSimpleCon.<init>(RDFSimpleCon.java:159)
    at nl.wur.ssb.RDFSimpleCon.Test.main(Test.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jena.tdb.sys.EnvTDB.processGlobalSystemProperties(EnvTDB.java:33)
    at org.apache.jena.tdb.TDB.init(TDB.java:252)
    at org.apache.jena.tdb.sys.InitTDB.start(InitTDB.java:29)
    at org.apache.jena.sys.JenaSystem.lambda$init$2(JenaSystem.java:116)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.apache.jena.sys.JenaSystem.forEach(JenaSystem.java:191)
    at org.apache.jena.sys.JenaSystem.forEach(JenaSystem.java:168)
    at org.apache.jena.sys.JenaSystem.init(JenaSystem.java:114)
    at org.apache.jena.tdb.TDBFactory.<clinit>(TDBFactory.java:40)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: The apache library gives NPE, and from the source code, it seems like it didn't create a context. Can you provide more information? https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/master/jena-tdb/src/main/java/org/apache/jena/tdb/sys/EnvTDB.java

Comment: For gradle shadowJar, use "mergeServiceFiles()"

Comment: Just noticed on the main website of Jena that version 12 was available, that in combination with the mergeServiceFiles() did the trick!

Comment: @AndyS if you post your solution as an Answer I can accept it properly.

Comment: Thanks - now it's confirmed I'll add it to the Jena "repack" documentation as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java ServiceLoader files need to be merged when creating a repackaged jar file.

For Gradle, this is done with "mergeServiceFiles()" when using the `shadowJar`.

https://jena.apache.org/documentation/notes/jena-repack.html has the instructions for the Maven shade plugin.